# Sorting a Custom List based on int field

Tags: c#, list

I have a simple class that I add to a list, and once I have everything added I want to sort by `GridFieldOrder`, this should be simple but I'm not able to put it together.

```
List<UserSearchSetupReOrderIng> UserSearchSetupOmega = new List<UserSearchSetupReOrderIng>();

 class UserSearchSetupReOrderIng
{
    public string UID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int GridFieldOrder { get; set; }
    public string Column { get; set; }
}
```

So basically if I have 100 items in my list, I just want to sort all of them by `GridFieldOrder` in order of lowest to highest value. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OrderBy` extension method should do the trick.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

```
var sortedList = UserSearchSetupOmega.OrderBy(i => i.GridFieldOrder);
```

for ascending order. (`OrderByDescending` for descending order.)

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq - [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) - Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a key.

```
List<UserSearchSetupReOrderIng> sortedData = UserSearchSetupOmega
                                .OrderBy(data => data.GridFieldOrder).ToList();
```

If you want it in descending order then  use [Enumerable.OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855) extension method simply as above:

```
List<UserSearchSetupReOrderIng> sortedData = UserSearchSetupOmega
                        .OrderByDescending(data => data.GridFieldOrder).ToList();
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
var sorted = UserSearchSetupOmega.OrderBy(i => i.GridFieldOrder)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<UserSearchSetupReOrderIng> UserSearchSetupOmega = 
                      new List<UserSearchSetupReOrderIng>();

var sortedList = UserSearchSetupOmega.OrderBy(u => u.GridFieldOrder);
```